# Transfer Apple Wallet passes from one developer account to another

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I'm using the [Apple Wallet API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH1-SW1) to generate Apple Wallet passes and deliver them to my users. I'm also pushing updates to passes I delivered as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1).

The developer account I'm using is my personal account and I'd like to stop using it and start using my company's account. I've already set up my company's developer account and I'm already generating passes and updating them with the new account but **I want to know if there is a way to transfer the passes I've already created with my personal account to my company's account and allowing me to update these passes using my company's account**.

Every pass has a field called `teamIdentifier` and every pass is generated by signing it with a certificate. As far as I know, a certificate I generated using my personal account can only update passes with the team identifier of my personal account. I'm trying to understand if Apple allow to "transfer the ownership" of a pass from one account to another (by either updating the team identifier, sharing the certificate I generated from my personal account to my company's account, or any other way)

I know apps can be transferred between two developer accounts so I hope this will be possible too.